# Use RouteJs in TypeScript

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, typescript

I have a project that works with Knockout and jQuery, but because there are many viewmodels involved, I have decided to move to TypeScript. Integrating Knockout with TypeScript went rather well until I came across the following issue: RouteJs is used in the js files to generate routes.

In the view:

```
<script src="@RouteJs.RouteJsHandler.HandlerUrl"></script>
```

In the viewmodel file:

```
this.openProject = function (project) {
    if (!project.someBoolFunction()) {
        window.location = Router.action('SomeController', 'SomeAction', { id: project.dbId() });
    } else if (project.someBoolFunction() && project.someOtherBoolFunction()) {
        window.location = Router.action('SomeController', 'SomeOtheAction', { id: project.dbId() });
    }
    else {
        window.location = Router.action('SomeController', 'TheThirdAction', { id: project.dbId() });
    }
};
```

Now, as you can guess, the compiler has no idea what the`Router` object is all about. Is there any way to indicate to the compiler the source of this object?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a RouteJS type definition file [here](https://github.com/Daniel15/RouteJs/issues/30).